# Preference button displays a Open with Browser or MyApp dialog using Intent and action.VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a preference layout, something like this:

```
    <Preference
            android:title="@string/imagesPreferenceTitle"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_images"
            android:key="@string/imagesPrefs">
        <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="content://ex.my-app.com/preferences/images">    
        </intent>
```

When this is clicked, the MainActivity is supposed to handle this intent. Here is its `AndroidManifest.xml` declaration:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                    android:scheme="content"
                    android:host="ex.my-app.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/preferences">
            </data>
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Testing on an Alcatel running KitKat, I get a pop-up dialog asking me whether I should view this content using a Browser or MyApp.
On other devices/os versions it is okay - MyApp always handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, presumably that device has something named "browser" that handles `ACTION_VIEW` for `content:` `Uri` values, for whatever MIME type is associated with that `Uri`.

If you are trying to only match that activity, get rid of `android:action` and probably `android:data`, and [use `android:targetClass` and `android:targetPackage`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Intents). IOW, use an explicit `Intent`, not an implicit `Intent`.

Comment: This looks great, however, how do I differentiate (in the activity) between two `Preference`s for example the one from my question - `preferences/images` and say another one `preferences/sounds`

Comment: @J.K.: Well, unless you really have a `ContentProvider` supporting that authority string, I really don't recommend that. Use some custom action or MIME type, I guess, but still use `targetClass` and `targetPackage`. Those make the `Intent` explicit, so it will always go to your designated activity. The rest of the `Intent` information, like the action string, is merely payload.

Comment: I am going to set android:action and then in my MainActivity check intent.getAction().equals...